# Using git svn on a repo created with svn2git

Tags: git, svn, svn2git

We are migrating an old SVN repository to Git. This worked pretty well with [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git). Now we want to exclusively work on git but need to mirror any new git commits to the old SVN repository. This is necessary because some production systems still are deployed through SVN.

So I tried to use `git svn` on the same repository where I ran `svn2git` before. I'm not an expert (yet) but i thought, something like this should do the trick:

```
$ git svn dcommit --interactive
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history.
Perhaps the repository is empty. at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 780.
```

I also tried to get some information about the imported SVN data:

```
$ git svn info
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history
```

So it seems as if `svn2git` did some magic and left `git svn` in an "unconfigured state".
As far as I know git has to keep some references to map the SVN commits to git commits. The opposite command `svn2git --rebase` works: it fetches any new SVN commits and applies them to the git repo. So the data seems to be there and usable by `svn2git` (which AFAIK is based on `git svn`).

So how can I make `git svn` work? Or is there another way how we can backport git commits to SVN from that new repo (without starting from scratch)?

Comment: So you're trying to use `git svn` to commit directly in the old `SVN` repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "git svn rebase".

I faced exactly the same issue and used a wrapper script hosted @vhttps://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git.
Please take come time to read [SVN to GIT migration failed using svn2git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890247/svn-to-git-migration-failed-using-svn2git/13985703#13985703).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can not really judge if it works, because since we couldn't solve the problem in time, we've now used a different approach. I'll accept it as correct answer anyway ;).

Comment: Actually `git svn rebase` gives the same error message as `git svn info`: "Unable to determine upstream SVN information from working tree history", so it doesn't work.